# REST API - Security concerns

Tags: java, rest, firebase, struts2, google-signin

So this is one of my methods which fetches a user's profile:

```
public static UserProfile getUserProfile(String uid) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(uid)) {
            return null;
        }
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        UserProfile userProfile = null;
        try {
            userProfile = (UserProfile) session.createQuery("from " + UserProfile.class.getSimpleName() + " where uid = :uid").setParameter("uid", uid).uniqueResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        if (userProfile != null) {
            return userProfile;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is mapped to www.example.com/getUserProfile - I feel like this is such a hack able API. Anybody could start guessing UID, the whole database is structured around UID. All of the API is in the front end. Anybody can see what methods I have and what that method accepts as an argument. Am I overthinking here or am I really missing something here? Firebase provides UID upon a successful login. How do I really verify that the user is actually who the user says he/she is? What does that even do for me; that I've verified the user? Like, okay, I've verified the user who is actually a hacker, I still don't have anything.

Comment: "How do I really verify that the user is actually who the user says he/she is?" - That's called [authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/). And it should happen _before_ you allow getting a user profile ...

Comment: Guessing a real UID is pretty hard. On purpose. It's harder than guessing a password. What's your specific concern? How do you authenticate?

Comment: Users authenticate with the api provided by underlined framework. You can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about the security of your database (and you should be), you need to be using security rules to limit access to parts of a database that authenticated users should only have access to.

There's a tremendous amount to learn about security rules to be effective, but the best place to start is [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).  For your case in particular, read about [user based security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).

Comment: I'm using my own database, MySql.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for something like custom auth:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth

as you are using your own MySql db as you mentioned in the comments. This allows you to integrate firebase authentication with your own custom methods.

Or an alternative is using firebase admin or functions to access the api while setting the firebase layer to manage the authentication and users.